# How to simplify my code using stream or lambda

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-stream

```
String convSummary(String l) {
    String s = l.toLowerCase(), r ="";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ;i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd' || c == 'e')
            r += (char) (c & 0x5f);
        if(c == 'v' || c == 'w' || c == 'x' || c == 'y' || c == 'z')
            r += c;
    }
    return r;
}
```

How i can simplify my code using stream or lambda
i'm beginner , i want learn more about lambda and stream
Thanks for helping ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `String.chars()` to get a stream of characters,
but there are more important optimizations to make here:

- Don't concatenate strings character by character. Use a `StringBuilder`.
- Use `else if` instead of two `if` when the conditions are mutually exclusive (a character `c` will never be *at the same time* one of "abcde" *and* "vwxyz")
- If the characters to check are in an ASCII range, use a condition on the range rather than checking the values one by one

Putting the above together:

```
String convSummary2(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    s.chars().map(Character::toLowerCase).forEach(c -> {
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'e') {
            sb.append((char)(c & 0x5f));
        } else if ('v' <= c && c <= 'z') {
            sb.append((char) c);
        }
    });
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to run your code in parallel then Janos's answer is great, but we should strive to always make code that can easily be parallelized by simply switching the parallel intermediate operation on.

So, to convert your code using streams/lambdas; use the `if` conditions criteria within the `filter` intermediate operation, utilise `map` to do the logic within the if statement, then `collect` it into a string.

```
return
      s.toLowerCase()
       .chars()
       .filter(i -> 'a' <= i && i <= 'e' ||
                    'v' <= i && i <= 'z')
       .map(i -> 'a' <= i && i <= 'e' ?
                  (char)(i & 0x5f) :
                  (char)i)
       .mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char)i))
       .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

And you can easily parallelize this by just invoking the `parallel()` intermediate operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
int z=(int)c;
  if(z>=97 && z<=101) //these are the ascii value of the letters
  {
    //code for if c is either a,b,c,d,e   
    System.out.println("a,b,c,d,e");
  }
  else if(z>=118 && z<=122){
      //code for if c is either v,w,x,y,z
      System.out.println("v,w,x,y,z");
  }
```

Comment: Where’s the sense in replacing `'a'` with `97` or replacing `'e'` with `101`? You are making the code less readable without any reason, creating the need for a clarification comment like `//these are the ascii value of the letters` which still requires extra effort on the reader’s side to find out to which letters these numbers correspond…

Comment: I didn't view the above solution while submitting my own